# No warning in case of no initialization despite -Wall in gcc

Tags: gcc, initialization, gcc-warning, uninitialized-constant

the following code does'nt produce any warning when compiled with "-Wall" option in gcc:

```
int main ()
{
    int c, i;


    for ( ; i < 10; i++ ) {
        c += i;
    }

    return c;
}
```

This is the command used to build the source:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall 1.c
$
```

It returns without any message.
I would expect a "warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function", and the same warning for the 'c' variable.

Any idea about this behavior?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis performed by `-Wall` is very limited without optimizations. Warning is successfully detected with `-O1` or `-O2`.

Comment: Thank you! In fact, with -O1 the warnings are correctly signaled. I have been using gcc for years and never noticed it. Good to know!!